# Can I insert an object by value (copying) from one std::vector to another?

Tags: c++, call-by-value

(I realized that it was a copy-paste-mistake in my program. But the reason, why I get exactly that error message could still be interesting for somebody else, therefore, I updated the question.)

I have the following code snippet which copies the elements of one vector into another vector. Maybe this could be solved more elegantly, but that shall not be the question here (except if it's absolutely stupid what I'm trying to do, of course.)

```
void DomainClass::addMembers(vector<DomainMember*>& d){
    for(int i = 0; i < d.size(); i ++){
        this->domains.push_back(d[i]);
    }
}
```

The vector `this->domains` is a member with definition:

```
vector<Domain*> domains;
```

The compiler tells me: error:

```
reference to type 'const value_type' (aka 'Domain *const') could not bind to an lvalue of type 'value_type' (aka 'DomainMember *')
```

I basically understand the problem when I'd like to handle objects BY REFERENCE, BUT in that case, I'd like to insert the elements of `d` BY VALUE into `domains`. How can I tell the compiler that he should just make a copy instead of passing references?

Comment: Where is your MCVE? Vectors _do_ make copies so you're misunderstanding something.

Comment: Is it possible that your member variable `domains` contains elements of type `DomainMember*` but the argument vector contains elements of type `Domain*`? Btw. `std::vector::push_back()` pushes elements by value, so that's not the problem.

Comment: Please edit question by adding declaration of member vector "domains".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the error tells you is that you try to put an object of type `DomainMember*` (in `d`) in an object of class `Domain*` (in `domains`). The compiler does not know how to cast from `DomainMember` to `Domain`.

The problem is not with the copy, it is with the fact that the type of `domains` should be be `vector<DomainMember*>` (or `d` should be a `vector<Domain*>`, your call) for your `push_back` to work.